# Shape assertions and declarations in tensroflow

Tags: tensorflow

I use tf.strided_slice to get one value out of the 1d tensor. Unfortunately, inferred shape is ?. How can I assert/declare that it has shape [1]?

P.S. I used reshape, but it might have performance implications in some cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`x.set_shape()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Tensor#set_shape) to provide additional information about the shape of this tensor that cannot be inferred from the graph alone.

You can get more information from the [FAQ](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/faq#tensor_shapes):

> The tf.Tensor.set_shape method updates the static shape of a Tensor
>   object, and it is typically used to provide additional shape
>   information when this cannot be inferred directly. It does not change
>   the dynamic shape of the tensor.